# print term frequency list (have distribution)

Tags: python, nltk

I have everything almost sorted, but because I want the top 2k unique words, I'm getting a super jumbled distribution. I'm eventually going to use this to build a dictionary, but I want to see which are the most common 2k words so I can choose the pertinent ones for the dictionary. Anyhow, see code below. How do I amend to get a list where I see (word)(count)? Does not have to be limited to 2k, would be nice to see count for all? Thanks!

```
>>> fileObj = codecs.open( "/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/ALLstories.txt", "r", "Latin-1" )
chattanooga_stories = fileObj.read()
>>> import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> lowered_stories = chattanooga_stories.lower()
>>> word_list = lowered_stories.split()
>>> filtered_stories = [w for w in word_list if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
>>> fdist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in filtered_stories)
>>> print(fdist)
<FreqDist with 7031 samples and 19893 outcomes>
>>> top_2k = [ ]
>>> top_2k = fdist.most_common(2000)
>>> fdist.plot(2000, cumulative=True)
```

Comment: You might want to remove punctuation too.

Comment: Edit your question to show the output(just a small part) as well. I assumed it was a dict.

Answer (score 1):

You do get the counts of the various words when you use most_common(). Use items method to get a list of items in sorted order (most frequent first).

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(filtered_stories)    #filtered_stories is already lowercase
print(fdist)
top_2k = [ ]
top_2k = fdist.most_common(2000)
tok_2k.items() #should give you a sorted list
```

Comment: '>>> top_2k.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items''

Comment: so I used print(top_2k) to print the list, but it's not very exportable into Excel, where I'd like to end up with one column of words an adjacent column with the count. Any tips on how to better get it to that format OR to write it to a file like that? Thanks :)